# multiple $interval Angular JS prob

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3, angularjs-directive

The output of this is not exactly what i want and i don't know where is the problem, normally it should finish the first interval after that start the second loop but the result is like that :

my j : 4

my i : 4

my j : 3

my i : 5

my j : 2

my i : 6

but what I want is to finish the first loop after that start the second.

Thanks in advance

```
        var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(53, 91);
        var j = $scope.map.zoom;
        $interval(function () {
            $scope.map.setZoom(j--);
            console.log(" my j :"+j);
        }, 500, 3);// Zoom out after 0.5 sec

        $scope.map.panTo(pos); // Pan map to that position

        var i = $scope.map.zoom;
        $interval(function () {
            $scope.map.setZoom(i++);
            console.log("my i :"+i);
        }, 500, 3);// Zoom in after 0.5 sec
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start the second interval when the promise from the first interval resolves:

```
$interval(function () {
    $scope.map.setZoom(j--);
    console.log(" my j :"+j);
}, 500, 3).then(function() {
    var i = $scope.map.zoom;
    $interval(function () {
        $scope.map.setZoom(i++);
        console.log("my i :"+i);
    }, 500, 3);
});
```

Comment: Thank you it's working, but i don't know why there is a slight time before starting the second interval, do you have an idea why ?

Comment: thats because it takes 500 ms until it starts to run. you can do one $scope.map.setZoom before the interval, and change the count from 3 to 2